# What does Windows 8 Core upgrade to?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade

I have a laptop (A Gateway NV52L23u to be exact) that is getting a Windows 10 upgrade, I currently have Windows 10 Home 64-bit disc that I have been using to upgrade Windows 7 Home Premium machines around the house. The thing is the NV52L series comes with Windows 8 'Core' (the standard version, not Pro or Enterprise). And [in this article](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/3887/windows-10-upgrade-matrix-which-version-you-get-for-free), it states that Windows 8 (all versions) are excluded from the upgrade.

But then I thought, that's only for the Windows Update way of upgrading, what about upgrading through a disc? So, I put my disc in, expecting failure, and for some reason, it let me get in the installer and got to the 'We are ready to upgrade' screen. At this point, I had a deep feeling that something was terribly wrong. I quit the installer, then I contemplated why it let me upgrade when Microsoft said no.

Maybe Windows 8 ran the executable in Compatibility Windows 7 mode, and the installer believed it was upgrading a Windows 7 machine. Or maybe the executable does not have code to differentiate Windows 8 and 8.1?

So, I leave the question, can I upgrade Windows 8 'Core' from a disc without running into problems? And is the disc made to upgrade Windows 8 'Core'?

If you need any further information, please let me know, I will update the question.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe you are supposed to upgrade to 8.1 (its free) first as its pretty much mandatory update.

Comment: I know, but that is currently being an issue so i wanted to upgrade straight

Comment: Also, if I upgrade to Windows 8.1 will all my stuff still be on the system, or will it be deleted. I know Windows 7 to Windows 10 does not delete, but does Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 delete?

Comment: 8.1 is just like service pack in XP, everything will (should ;) stay.

Comment: OK, but can i upgrade straight through Windows 8 to 10 or will problems happen

Comment: The Windows 10 upgrade *SHOULD* install all the necessary updates before installing Windows 10.

Comment: @Curtis ok, I'm not sure tho, should I just try?

Comment: Some people have said it will work here, https://www.quora.com/Can-I-upgrade-directly-from-Windows-8-to-Windows-10-skipping-8-1 and here http://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/upgrade-windows-8-to-windows-10.html I would back up any important files and give it a try. Worst case you can do a clean install as long as Windows 10 activates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this picture by Windows Central:

[image: Upgrade Matrix]

Windows 8 will upgrade to Windows 10 through ISO or Disc upgrade, not through Windows Update (Over-the-air).